# cannot read utf-8 buffer from web server

Tags: c++, utf-8

I'm writing a simple web crawler with C++.

It connects to a web server and sends a "GET" request, and then it receives the reply from the web server.

This is the piece of code I use to do this:

```cpp
CHttpHeader reqHeader = websock.GenerateRequestHeader(url, nullptr);
dwResponse = websock.SendRequest(url, reqHeader, nullptr, nullptr);
if (dwResponse == 0)    {
    //::MessageBoxA(this->GetSafeHwnd(), "error to send http request", 0, 0);
    return;
}

//char*strstr = "병맛메로나";

//  Receive Response
const int bufferSize = 1024 * 1024 * 1;
char * buffer = new char[bufferSize * 10];
char *tbuffer = new char[bufferSize];

int recvLen = 0;
DWORD dwNextOffset = 0;


//setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

while (websock.HasMoreResponse())   {
    recvLen = websock.Recv(tbuffer, bufferSize);

    ::memcpy(buffer + dwNextOffset, tbuffer, recvLen);
    dwNextOffset+= recvLen;
}
```

The server reply will be copied into `buffer` with `dwNextOffset` length.

Every thing works fine to connect to the server and receive the reply correctly.  But, in some cases with a UTF-8 encoded reply, I cannot read the HTML tag from the buffer. Its all gibberish.

I guess this is due to client/server OS differences. Because I am on Windows and when the web server is IIS, which is highly likely running on Windows, there's no problem to read UTF-8 encoded characters. But, in some cases of Apache, this problem happens.

Is the UTF-8 format different between OSes?

If so, can I convert to MBCS correctly?

---

Edit: Here's the file saving part:

```cpp
FILE* fp = nullptr;
::fopen_s(&fp, "result", "wb");
::fwrite(buffer, 1, dwOffset, fp);
::fclose(fp);
```

and the result is..

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 27 Feb 2018 12:19:19 GMT
X-UA-Compatible: IE=10
Expires: Sat, 01, Jan 1970 22:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
P3P: CP="ALL DSP COR MON LAW IVDi HIS IVAi DELi SAMi OUR LEG PHY UNI ONL DEM STA INT NAV PUR FIN OTC GOV"
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: ko-KR
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-UA-Device-Type: pc
Content-Length: 49043
Connection: close

?      醬??/影?-~퍏뙗*쿭돃?긥먉^...
```

---

Edit: Max Vollmer, you were right.  Using `Accept-Encoding : identity` on the request resolved some of the issues.  But there's another problem.

If I use this code:

```
char *strstr = "병맛메로나";
std::string tstr(strstr);
```

`tstr` works correctly.

But, if I make `buffer` into a `std::string`, it has gibberish again.

```
std::string tstr(buffer);
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: UTF-8 format is the same in all OS. How do you know that you are reading UTF-8 data?

Comment: Really if the probem is that you cannot interpret the data in `buffer` correctly then you should show the code that tries to interpret the `buffer`. Why just post the code that you know to be correct? Post the code that might be wrong.

Comment: If the data is UTF-8 encoded, you need to decode it. Where do you do that?

Comment: _"I cannot read html tag from buffer. Its all gibrish"_ Where is that attempted? Show the code. In what way is it gibberish?

Comment: `char*strstr = "병맛메로나"; std::string tstr(strstr);` This cannot and does not work, why do you think it does?

Answer (score 4):

**Your 1st problem, compression:**

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Your data is compressed, you have to decompress it. See [Content-Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding). There are plenty of C++ libraries for doing so.

Alternatively you can send a `Accept-Encoding: identity` header with your request, so the server doesn't send compressed data. See [Accept-Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding).

**Your 2nd problem, encoding:**

You can't just do `std::string tstr(buffer);` if buffer is UTF-8 encoded. First, this doesn't decode any UTF-8 characters at all. You don't even tell it that your data is UTF-8 encoded, how should it know? Second, any characters that need more than 8 byte can't be represented by a single `char`, and std::string uses `char` for its characters, so `std::string` can never hold the textual representation of UTF-8 encoded data.

You might be confused about what `char` actually is. **It's an integer with 8 bit size.**

Since UTF-8 encodes special characters with multiple bytes, those characters will be stored in multiple chars in your char array. When you simply create an `std::string` with that char array, it will simply interprete each char as one character, which is wrong.

You must decode your UTF-8 data into a multibyte string, e.g. `std::wstring`, or use some third party library that provides some string class that supports UTF-8 out of the box. Or just write the data to a file and open that file with a text editor that supports UTF-8, it should autodetect the encoding. Really depends on what you're trying to do.

Here's a simple way to convert UTF-8 encoded data to a `std::wstring`:

```
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> converter;
std::wstring text = converter.from_bytes(buffer);
```

Comment: Thanks Max. But I still got a problem. How can I decode UTF-8 data into char buffer?

Comment: @JayKim You can't decode UTF-8 into a char array. That literally makes no sense. `char` is 8 bit. You can have UTF-8 encoded data in a `char array`, where special characters are encoded as 2 or more `char`s, but never can one `char` contain a multibyte character. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Max. your conversion worked to convert into wstring. :) Anyway, char buffer, I meant multi-byte string.

Comment: `char` *might* be 8 bits - you'll have to look at `CHAR_BIT` to be sure of that...

Comment: @TobySpeight While not factually wrong, I think your comment is misleading, as it implies that `char` sizes vary widely on mainstream platforms, which they do not. Systems with a `char` size different from `8 bit` are rare, esoteric and usually really old, and they are definitely not systems where you write a web client that parses html. Also we are talking `C++` here, so better use `std::numeric_limits<char>::digits`, as `CHAR_BIT` might not be defined on every platform (which is actually more likely than having your software run on a system with a non-8-bit char size.)

Comment: Sure, `char` is often 8 bits on the platforms I develop for.  But I would never claim that it **is** 8 bits as if that were a fact.

Comment: FYI, some web servers are actually broken and don't handle `Accept-Encoding: identity` (I've encountered them before), despite being a requirement of the HTTP spec. You shouldn't send an `Accept-Encoding` header at all, unless you are prepared to handle non-`identity` encodings (like `gzip`). A web server will not send a response in a non-`identity` encoding unless you explicitly ask it to. `identity` is the default encoding when `Accept-Encoding` is not present.

Comment: The fact that the failing responses had `Content-Encoding: gzip` means the requests must have had some variation of `Accept-Encoding: gzip` in them (`Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip` is commonly used), even though the code wasn't actually prepared to decompress any `gzip`-encoded data.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The default is `Accept-Encoding: *`, a server is then free to chose whatever it prefers, including `gzip`.

Comment: @MaxVollmer: OK then. I must have been thinking about this clause in RFC 2616: "*If no Accept-Encoding field is present in a request, the server MAY assume that the client will accept any content coding. In this case, **if "identity" is one of the available content-codings, then the server SHOULD use the "identity" content-coding**... Note: If the request does not include an Accept-Encoding field, and if the "identity" content-coding is unavailable, then content-codings commonly understood by HTTP/1.0 clients (i.e., "gzip" and "compress") are preferred;...*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau Exactly, _SHOULD_, not _MUST_. The server is free to chose.